# how to disable AUTH (login) in tinymce editor

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

i use codeigniter php framework, and i have TinyMce editor, but problem is: user should login in 2 times to write some post,one login on system login and second login in tinyMce login, how i can disable login of tinyMce editor?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Are you saying the user at the moment has to login twice, or you want them to login twice? Can you post some code?

Comment: yea, user have to login twice insead once only!.. i dont want twice :D just once.. but tinymce login is problem ..

Comment: I thought TinyMCE was simply a Javascript WYSIWYG editor? Can you post your controller code?

Comment: my session of logged user in system, is connected with tinxyMce login adn when user is logged in he can use TinyMCE, but sometimes session breaks, and logout user automaticaly, thats is problem..(sorry i dont have here code)

Comment: It's hard without seeing the code. You could check your session configuration to make sure everything is as should be. ./application/config/config.php - In this file, search for "sess" and check the config options are all OK.